# Poylmorphism, overridden method used in constructor - C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am trying to understand if my mistake comes from a design problem or a code error.  My search pointed me out to Slicing issue but I don't see this being the issue here.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

    class BaseA {
    public:
        BaseA(const std::string &n)
            : name(n)
        {}
        virtual ~BaseA() 
        {};
        virtual void print() const
        {
            std::string str("");
            str += name;
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }

    protected:
        std::string name;
    };

    class BaseB : public BaseA {
    public:
        BaseB(const std::string &n, const std::string &v)
            : BaseA(n), value(v)
        { 
            load();
        }
        virtual ~BaseB() 
        {};
        virtual void load(){
             c = 'B';
        }
        char getC() {
            return c;
        }
        void print() const{
            std::string str("");
            str += name;
            str += ' ';
            str += value;
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
    protected:
        char c;
    private:
        std::string value;
        int data = 0;
    };

    class BaseC : public BaseB {
    public:
        BaseC(const std::string &n, const std::string &v)
            : BaseB(n, v) 
        {
        }
        void load() override{
             c = 'C';
        }
    };

    int mainTest() 
    {
        std::vector<BaseB*> vec;
        vec.push_back(new BaseB("John", "singer"));
        vec.push_back(new BaseC("Raoul", "wannabe"));   
        for (BaseB *obj : vec)
        {
            obj->print();
            std::cout << "load class: " << obj->getC() << std::endl;
        }
        return(0);
    };
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
John singer 
load class: B 
Raoul wannabe 
load class: C
```

but I get B for both.   Does it mean that in the constructor, it is not possible to use an overridden class?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not impossible, but it may not do what you want.

Recall that for `BaseC`, the construction order is `BaseA`, `BaseB`, `BaseC`.

While `BaseB` is being constructed (constructor executing), there is no such object as a `BaseC`, even if it is being constructed as part of a `BaseC` construction.

The standard therefore mandates that during the constructor (and destructor) of `BaseB`, calling `load()` will result in `BaseB::load()` being called. Not `BaseC::load()`